# Two coloring a tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees, coloring

Suppose we color the nodes of a tree $T=(V,E)$ with two colors, red and blue, so that any two adjacent nodes have different colors.

Can we claim that

1. If there is an even-length path between two nodes $u,v$, then they have different colours.
2. If there is an odd-length path between two nodes $u,v$, then they have different colours.

For 1. I think it's false because if we assign the same colors to $u,v$, then we can't color $T$. My question is are there a stronger proof for 1 and 2? because i think maybe my proof is wrong.

Comment: This does not sound right. In many cases if you color $u$ and $v$ the same color you might not be able to color the rest of tree they way you want. E.g.  $p(A, p(C,D))$ where $p(x,y)$ stands for the parent of $x$ and $y$. The leaves $A$ and $D$ cannot be colored with the same color, no can they be connected by an even-length path.

Comment: @free Your question is not entirely clear. That said, I suspect that statement 1 should say "for any two nodes $u,v$ for which there is an even-length path between them, $u$ and $v$ have different colors". If that is the case, then 1 is wrong and 2 is correct.

Comment: Can you explain why 2 is true?

Comment: 1 is wrong, any even path will have the same color. Imagine it iteratively coloured, starting from length 2 what obvious must have same color around the node

Comment: What does it mean for a path to be "colored with different colors"? Any path between two different vertices will have both red and blue vertices on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that 1 is false but your argument is not very clear.

If vertex $u$ is coloured red then any vertex, $v$, distance $1$ from $u$ must be coloured blue.

Then any vertex, $w$, distance $1$ from $v$ must be coloured red and so on ...

As an exercise you could write out a proof by induction that any vertex distance $n$ from $u$ is coloured blue if and only if $n$ is odd.